# jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over string, cannot execute unique problem

Tags: json, csv, parsing, unique, jq

We are trying to parse a JSON file to a tsv file. We are having problems trying to eliminate duplicate Id with unique.

JSON file

```
[
   {"Id": "101",
    "Name": "Yugi"},   
   {"Id": "101",
    "Name": "Yugi"},
   {"Id": "102",
    "Name": "David"},      
]
```

```sh
cat getEvent_all.json | jq -cr '.[] | [.Id] | unique_by(.[].Id)'
```

jq: error (at :0): Cannot iterate over string ("101")

Comment: Did you try `jq 'unique_by(.Id)' file`?

Comment: @oguzismail Yeah I did. I got the same error. I don't understand why. I have tried converting id to number.

Comment: Given your sample I can't reproduce the error with `unique_by(.Id)`

Comment: I fixed the problem with cat getEvent_all.json | ./jq '.[] | {id: .Id|tonumber}' | ./jq -s '. | unique'  by streaming all the output into an array then parsing it with unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable approach would be to use `unique_by`, e.g.:

```
unique_by(.Id)[]
| [.Id, .Name]
| @tsv
```

Alternatively, you could form the pairs first:

```
map([.Id, .Name])
| unique_by(.[0])[]
| @tsv
```

#### `uniques_by/2`

For very large arrays, though, or if you want to respect the original ordering, a sort-free alternative to `unique_by` should be considered.  Here is a suitable, generic, stream-oriented alternative:

```
def uniques_by(stream; f):
  foreach stream as $x ({};
     ($x|f) as $s
     | ($s|type) as $t
     | (if $t == "string" then $s
        else ($s|tostring) end) as $y
     | if .[$t][$y] then .emit = false
       else .emit = true | (.item = $x) | (.[$t][$y] = true)
       end;
     if .emit then .item else empty end );
```